# changing active control using fontdialog and RichEdit

Tags: delphi, dialog, delphi-xe2

I migrated from Delphi v7 to Delphi XE2. I am trying to use a fontdialog with two dbrichedit and a dbedit control. The code I used to accomplish the task works fine in Delphi v7, but it does not work with XE2. I think it must be some simple thing I have overlooked. I have worked on resolving the issue for over a week, but I am too close to the problem to see it I think.

I used a button to execute fontdialog and an apply event to manipulate the text.

Code:

```
if ActiveControl is TDBEdit then 
  with ActiveControl as
  TdbEdit do
    Font.Assign(TFontDialog(Sender).Font)
else if ActiveControl is TDBRichEdit then 
  with ActiveControl as TDBRichEdit do
    SelAttributes.Assign(TFontDialog(Sender).Font)
```

Nothing happens.

Is there a property for form1 that I have overlooked?

Comment: That code could not have worked in D7 more than in XE2.

Answer (score 4):

You must save the value of the [`ActiveControl`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.ActiveControl) property in a variable, before to use it, because when the [Vcl.Dialogs.TFontDialog.OnApply](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.TFontDialog.OnApply) event is raised the `ActiveControl` return the current active control which in this case is the button which you pressed. check this sample [`FontDialogOnApply (Delphi)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeSamples/en/FontDialogOnApply_%28Delphi%29).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did what you suggested and re-wrote my code after the example "FontDialogOnApply (Delphi). The problem still exists. When I highlight the text in my RichEdit controls and select text attributes in FondDialog, then click apply nothing happens. It is the same with the edit control.